# When and how did public nudity and sex become shameful and unacceptable?

Tags: social-psychology, evolution, evolutionary-psychology, sociology

I am thinking about it from the evolutionary perspective. For nudity, I thought that maybe nude bodies may be associated with a higher probability of infection and diseases due to exposed parts. I also thought that maybe there's a social reason such that it's considered a better social status to be dressed; as an indicator of wealth and security.

But then when you think about it, it's not necessarily nudity that is frowned upon, it's the exposure of private parts. Considering that our reproductive organs are also used to dispose bodily waste, it makes sense to associate some sort of negative emotion with them. But then again, why would female breasts be considered indecent?

Also, when it comes to sex, clothed intercourse is still considered shameful. Sex is not only considered as a private activity, but also as a sin by lot many religions; it's also associated with morality. Gluttony, also being a function of our greed and bodily pleasure, doesn't receive the same amount of repulsion as does sex. Wouldn't it make more sense for the society to promote sex considering that it increases the probability of the continuation of our species?

Comment: Wow, public nudity is a huge subject of a book I am in the middle of writing. To ask in one question like this would need an extensive answer and even then, the when and how can be opinion based and speculative depending on religious viewpoints etc. Unfortunately I feel this cannot be answered in one strict question such as this on here. You would need to split it up in component parts and ask it in different contexts such as history in history.se etc.

Comment: **Related:** https://psychology.stackexchange.com/questions/16831/psychological-effects-of-social-nudity **Loosly related:** https://psychology.stackexchange.com/questions/6123/are-there-studies-on-international-differences-on-sexualization

Comment: The _title_ of this question implies you either have a specific culture in mind which you do not mention explicitly, or you assume nudity and sex are considered shameful and unacceptable universally. Could you explicitly state/reference which one you hold to be true? This can help narrowing down the question to combat @Chris's comment. Most of the question body is unfounded hypothesizing based on your limited knowledge of the subject. I feel, instead, keeping the question short and asking about a single thing you need elaboration on, based on what you _do_ know, might be more useful.

Comment: To clarify, if you focus on the title of your question and try to make this more specific/explicit (you could, e.g., also elaborate on what you consider 'nudity', etc.), as opposed to trying to provide a potential answer in the question yourself, I feel this makes a really good question! The related questions @ChrisRogers linked to should clarify why making this more explicit is necessary.

Comment: Also related: https://psychology.stackexchange.com/q/1567/7001

Comment: Sex is also considered wholesome  by many religions when performed within the context of marriage. But generally speaking, "Out of sight, out of mind" applies, and when the mind dwells on sex, lots of sex may ensue, and when lots of sex ensues, the rapid propagation of disease may ensue. So to keep all this in check, clothes help. Plus they keep us warm and/or cool, and protect us from sunburn and abrasions. Win-win!